# Could the voting and accept links be made normal images so that they don't disappear in high contrast display modes?

Tags: feature-request, design, accessibility

**Upvote**, **downvote**, **accept answer** and **favorite** buttons appear on stackoverflow websites as background images. This limits accessibility of the site: If I view stackoverflow sites in High Contrast display schemes (in my case in Windows 8), these buttons are not displayed. The reason is clear: In order to improve text readability, High Contrast scheme disables all background images.

Is there any valid reason why buttons are kept as background images? Could they be converted to standard foreground graphics?

Comment: The logo (both site name and SE) too.

Comment: Does Elmer Fudd write your titles?  Can't decide whether to change the W's to V's, or change background to backgwound.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I'm not a native English speaker, my apologies. Feel free to edit the title.

Comment: No worries.  I was mostly making a joke at your expense.

Comment: Sprites. Foreground images can't be rolled into sprites, and sprites save a lot of HTTP requests.

Comment: @michaelb958 - maybe this case looks like a candidate for checkbox
**[x] Enhance accessibility** in **Preferences** section. Unchecked by default. It could be used to address any other future accessibility issues, too.

Comment: @miroxlav it's possible to auto detect the resolution/contrast/device and serve proper code. More complex coding, but if the team here wants, it's totally doable. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, thanks, it seems that SO [shows the way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921047/how-to-check-if-user-is-in-high-contrast-mode-via-javascript-or-css) :)